# programming with threads: output is changing after a series of runs

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<pthread.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<signal.h>
void sig(int signo)
{
    if(signo==SIGUSR1)
        printf("hiiii\n");
}
void * runner(void * param)
{
    signal(SIGUSR1,sig);
    while(1)
        sleep(1);
}
int main()
{
   pthread_t rid,sid;
   pthread_attr_t attr;
   pthread_attr_init(&attr);
   pthread_create(&sid,&attr,runner,NULL);  
   pthread_create(&rid,&attr,runner,NULL);
   //sleep(1);
   pthread_kill(sid,SIGUSR1);
   printf("hey\n");
   pthread_kill(rid,SIGUSR1);
   pthread_join(rid,NULL);
}
```

**output:**

```
harikrishna@harikrishna:~/Desktop/Ass3b_43$ ./a.out
User defined signal 1
harikrishna@harikrishna:~/Desktop/Ass3b_43$ ./a.out
User defined signal 1
harikrishna@harikrishna:~/Desktop/Ass3b_43$ ./a.out
User defined signal 1
harikrishna@harikrishna:~/Desktop/Ass3b_43$ ./a.out
User defined signal 1
harikrishna@harikrishna:~/Desktop/Ass3b_43$ ./a.out
User defined signal 1
harikrishna@harikrishna:~/Desktop/Ass3b_43$ ./a.out
User defined signal 1
harikrishna@harikrishna:~/Desktop/Ass3b_43$ ./a.out
User defined signal 1
harikrishna@harikrishna:~/Desktop/Ass3b_43$ ./a.out
hey
hiiii
hiiii
^C
harikrishna@harikrishna:~/Desktop/Ass3b_43$
```

Comment: Looks about right. The order in which threads will run is unpredictable. What's the question?

Comment: output is different why?
sometimes it is giving output as "User defined signal 1"
sometimes "hey hiii hiii"

Comment: Threads are identical

Comment: There's no guarantee that either thread gets to call `signal()` before it is sent `SIGUSR1` by the main thread.  There's no guarantee about whether the threads get to sleep.  Why doesn't the code `pthread_join(sid, NULL);`?  Basically, the beauty of threads, especially on multi-core systems, is that you can't predict what's going to be scheduled when.

Comment: Also, please make sure you indent output so that it looks like 'code'.  And in general we don't care about your prompt — use an abbreviated one (classically, just `$ `) to indicate the prompt, unless you're running as `root`, in which case `# ` is traditional, or you're using a C shell (no, on second thoughts, don't use a C shell).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you have is that you register the signal handler from the thread.
Since the threads are not synchronized, the signal can be send to the thread before the handler is registered.

When you see "`User defined signal 1`", that means that you send the signal to thread before the signal handler has been registered.

Since the signal handler is shared among thread, you not have to register it from the threads: you can do it before creating them:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<pthread.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<signal.h>

void sig(int signo)
{
    if(signo==SIGUSR1)
        printf("hiiii\n");
}

void * runner(void * param)
{        
    while(1)
        sleep(1);
}

int main()
{
   pthread_t rid,sid;
   pthread_attr_t attr;

   /* register signal handler */
   signal(SIGUSR1,sig);       

   /* create thread */
   pthread_attr_init(&attr);
   pthread_create(&sid,&attr,runner,NULL);  
   pthread_create(&rid,&attr,runner,NULL);

   /* send signals */
   pthread_kill(sid,SIGUSR1);
   printf("hey\n");
   pthread_kill(rid,SIGUSR1);

   /*terminate  thread*/
   pthread_cancel(sid);
   pthread_cancel(rid);

   /* join */
   pthread_join(sid,NULL);
   pthread_join(rid,NULL);
}
```

With this code, you still may have `hiii` and `hey` mixed, but you should no longer have `User defined signal 1`